# Win10: Game controller prevents screen saver

Tags: windows-10

My Game controller prevents the screen saver from starting. How do I solve that?

I used to solve that through the device manager, but now, when I click the device in the device manager, the power management tab is missing.

A related question: to find that the controller was the culprit I did manual testing. Is there a better way to find that? I'm noting that `powercfg -requests` returns nothing.

---

More info:

- The controller is a PS5 Dualsense, and it's detected as xbox 360 controller.
- There's no power management tab for the mouse and keyboard as well.

Comment: What model is the game controller? Is the power management tab missing for all devices?

Comment: I added this info.

Comment: Zohar, any luck fixing this? I'm seeing a very similar issue with the ps4 controller w/ the PS dongle.  Worked fine for me up until the most recent update. Took me a while to find the issue, but I can't seem to figure out how to fix it (short of unplugging the dongle).

Comment: No solution yet. I also posted on https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/win10-game-controller-prevents-screen-saver/1c64867e-5823-4dc7-8fe4-fddac17bb332?tm=1617658895901&auth=1

Answer (score 0):

My current hack until this bug is fixed:

```
# Toggle (disable/enable device) a game controller that prevents the screen saver from running; based on devcon.exe (from Windows Driver Kit)
# https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon-examples

import colorama, time, subprocess

devcon = r'"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Tools\x64\devcon.exe"'

def print_red( st ):
    print(colorama.Fore.RED + colorama.Style.BRIGHT + st + colorama.Style.RESET_ALL)

def print_green( st ):
    print(colorama.Fore.GREEN + colorama.Style.BRIGHT + st + colorama.Style.RESET_ALL)

def main():
    # query
    cmd = "%s status *game controller" % devcon
    out = subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8")
    print( out )

    if out.find( "1 matching device(s) found." ) != -1:
        print( 'Found' )
    else:
        print_red( 'Not found!' )
        input()
        return

    if out.find( "Driver is running." ) != -1:
        print_red( 'Disabling' )
        cmd = "%s disable *game controller" % devcon
        out = subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8")
        print( out )
    else:
        print_green( 'Enabling' )
        cmd = "%s enable *game controller" % devcon
        out = subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8")
        print( out )

    time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

EDIT

Strange, after doing disable/enable once, the screensaver works fine. Maybe the disable does something to the power management that the enable doesn't revert. So, a simple batch file (.bat) to disable/enable the driver on startup may be enough.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Tools\x64\devcon.exe" disable *game controller
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Tools\x64\devcon.exe" enable *game controller
```